# Add class to website based on post taxonomy

Tags: php, taxonomy, body-class

I want to write a class to the body of all pages posts and custom posts (IE entire site)

I am using a front end editor that allows logged in users to edit posts and keep them out of the back-end.

- I have a custom post-type "emergency status"
- It contains one post with a taxonomy "status"
- It has the terms extreme, severe, very-high, high, moderate.

I want to add a filter that checks the taxonomy of that post and then adds it to the body of the site.

Answer (score 1):

> - You can use the body_class filter in WordPress to add the Taxonomy Terms of a Custom Taxonomy as CSS classes to a post. The CSS class appears in the body element and is only used if the post has been assigned to the taxonomy.
> - The code goes in your functions.php file.

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'themeprefix_add_taxonomy_class' );
 // Add taxonomy terms name to body class
function themeprefix_add_taxonomy_class( $classes ){
    if( is_singular() ) {
        global $post;
        $taxonomy_terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'your_taxonomy'); // change to your taxonomy
        if ( $taxonomy_terms ) {
            foreach ( $taxonomy_terms as $taxonomy_term ) {
            $classes[] = 'tax_' . $taxonomy_term->slug;
            }
        }
    }
    return $classes;
}
```

- Change ‘your_taxonomy’ to the actual taxonomy, the body_class filter is fed the results from a foreach loop done on the custom taxonomy, if any of the terms of that custom taxonomy are used by the post, they are added to the $classes array, in the above instance they have a prefix of ‘tax_’ followed by the term – you can change this prefix to suit or simply not have one.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress already does this if your theme has been built correctly. Specifically, WP will add classes to the body tag if you used `body_class` and to the posts containing element if you used `post_class`

For example, if you install WordPress, the default Hello World post is uncategorized, and has the following classes:

```
post-1 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-uncategorized entry
```

Notice the `category-uncategorized` class.

Similarly the `<body>` tag has these classes:

```
post-template-default single single-post postid-1 single-format-standard wp-embed-responsive singular image-filters-enabled
```

Other classes get added depending on the context, e.g. a class gets added if the admin toolbar is showing, or if the user is logged in, etc